# Unable to get local host IP address from getsockname?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, localhost

I am able to get the port returned, but the IP is not.  Should I be using something else other than getsockname?  thx

```
        if ((sock = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
            c.Format("Socket Error:  %d", GetLastError());
            tcpMESSAGE = 1;
            break;
        }


        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;         
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(4000); //port setting    
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

        if (::bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
            c.Format("Bind Error:  %d", GetLastError());
            tcpMESSAGE = 1;
            break;
        }

        if(1==1){
            int len = sizeof server_addr;
            if(::getsockname(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&server_addr,&len) == -1)
                MessageBox("Error local host ip");

            c.Format("local addr %s:%u\n  errno: %d",inet_ntoa(server_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(server_addr.sin_port), errno);
            MessageBox(c);
        }
```

Comment: If `getsockname()` returns an error, it'll set `errno`. Trying to debug without knowing it is bound to be more difficult than it needs to be...

Comment: errno is 0 when I MessageBox the IP address and the port

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are binding to `INADDR_ANY`, but you have not connected the socket to a peer yet, so there is no IP for `getsockname()` to return.  After a connection has been established via `connect()` or `accept()`, then `getsockname()` can return the specific IP that is being used for that connection.  Binding alone is not enough, unless you bind to a specific IP, which you are not doing.

Comment: How can I display the IP address that the computer is given.  I need to display that IP address for iPod user to type in so they can connect.  thx

Comment: @jdl: There is no function in the BSD sockets API to enumerate the local IP addresses, but many operating systems provide a function `getifaddrs()` to do this.

Comment: In many cases, calling `gethostname()` followed by `gethostbyname()` will return the local IPs, but this is not 100% guaranteed, depending on the particular DNS configuration of the hostname. If `getifaddrs()` is available, use it, otherwise you have to use platform-specific APIs instead.

Comment: `gethostbyname` was obsolescent way back in 2001 and removed in POSIX 2008. The correct function to use is `getaddrinfo`.